# PlotLegend colour

Tags: legending

I'm using a plot with a black background and I have a plotlegend

```
PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[{Transmitted, Reflected, Energy Conservation, 
   "white"}, {{1, .75}, {0.7, 0.5}}]
```

How can I get the plot legend text colour to be white? It stays as black. I've tried putting a vector

```
{"white"}
```

inside the code but it clashes with the placing coordinates. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Plot[{x, 2 x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5}, Background -> Black, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Style[#, White] & /@ {Transmitted, Reflected, 
     Energy Conservation}, {{1, .75}, {0.7, 0.5}}]]
```

[image]

or use the third argument of `Placed` to specify the styling:

```
PlotLegends -> Placed[{Transmitted, Reflected, Energy Conservation},
    {{1, .75}, {0.7, 0.5}}, 
    Style[#, White] &]
```

> same picture

Alternatively, use the option `LabelStyle -> White` in `Plot`:

```
Plot[{x, 2 x, x^2}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 Background -> Black, 
 LabelStyle -> White,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{Transmitted, Reflected, Energy Conservation}, 
   {{1, .75}, {0.7, 0.5}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect thanks.